# vscode compile c++ : fatal error: too many input files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

（1）Here is the file directory：

```bash
$ pwd
/home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demo1
$ tree -a
.
├── .vscode
│   └── tasks.json
├── include
│   ├── add.hpp
│   └── minus.hpp
└── src
    ├── add.cpp
    ├── main.cpp
    └── minus.cpp

4 directories, 6 files
```

（2）This is task.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp 生成活动文件",
            "command": "/usr/bin/cpp",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "-I",
                "/home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demo1/include/**",
                "/home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demo1/src/**",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "调试器生成的任务。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

(3) the error :

```bash
/usr/bin/cpp -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demol/src/main.cpp 
-o -I /home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demol/include/** /home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demol/src/** /home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demol/src/main 
cpp: fatal error: too many input files
compilation terminated.
```

If removing    "/home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demo1/include/**",
"/home/devils1741/Documents/Projects/Demo1/src/**",

vscode can't find hpp

A single cpp file could be compile.

Is there anyone kind enough to help me? Tanks.

Comment: The `-I` parameter should just have the directory name, NOT all the files contained therein, which is what the `**` part does.

Comment: Recommendation: [For many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301), you should replace the screenshot with text. Practically nothing kills an otherwise-legitimate question on Stack Overflow faster than an image of text.

Comment: what's up with your `-o`?

Comment: You need a filename after `-o` (which is your output name, ie the name of the program you are building). You cannot use VSCode unless you have some idea of how the compiler you are using works. One of the many reasons VSCode is not for beginners. But if you are a beginner then at least follow the documentation very closely

Answer (score 0):

Your `tasks.json` file is wrong. You should re-generate it and make some adjustments to it.

1. remove `tasks.json` in `Demo1/.vscode`.
2. Open [Command Palette in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#:%7E:text=The%20most%20important%20key%20combination,provides%20access%20to%20many%20commands.). I guess you can press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to do that.
3. Input `Tasks: Configure Task` in Command Palette and press enter
4. Select `C/C++: g++ build active file`
5. A new `tasks.json` file will be generated. To recognize your configuration latter, you can rename the task's `lable` as `MyTask`.
6. Add a line in `args`: `"-I../include",`, which will include all header files in `include` and save the file.
7. Open `main.cpp` and open the Command Palette, input `Tasks: Run Task`, enter
8. Select `MyTask`, press enter. If all goes well, you can find a executable file generated in `src`

The whole `tasks.json` will be like this:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "MyTask",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I../include",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the directory will be like this:

```bash
.
├── .vscode
│   └── tasks.json
├── include
│   ├── add.hpp
│   └── minus.hpp
└── src
    ├── add.cpp
    ├── main
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── main.dSYM
    └── minus.cpp

5 directories, 7 files
```

`main.dSYM` is the debug file for MacOS, which might will not be generated on your platform, you can just ignore it.

---

Thank for json's suggestion, if you want to compiler all source files in `src` togeter, you can write another task and simply appending it in your `tasks.json`. The final json file will be like this:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "MyTask",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I../include",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Multiple Source File Build",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-I../include",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And you can run task `Multiple Source File Build` to generate the executable file.

Comment: This tasks.json is only good for compiling a single file. I think the implication of the question is that the OP wants to compile multiple files.

Comment: @john If the OP want to compile multiple source files together, then a makefile or a CMakeLists instead of `tasks.json` is worthy of consideration. Let's wait for the OP's reply/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!   :)   I'm not very familiar with vs code configuration causing this problem. I have already solved this problem by makefile.

Comment: @zhishennie Glad to hear that! VS Code is a good staff to code a single file, but if you just start to learn programming multiple source files on Linux, a better IDE such as CLion may suite you better. Clion uses CMakeLists instead of makefiles, which might be a little complex at the beginning. But after you get used to it, things will be much better.